# Issues installing Kali on Intel NUC

Tags: kali-linux

I just got an Intel NUC NUC6i5SYK that has 32 GB of RAM and a 1 TB SSD drive.

I downloaded the latest Kali image and used Rufus to `dd` write to a USB drive. I am able to start the installation no problem but then it dies in the middle, saying:

`installation step failed, the step is select and install software`

Everything was default, and nothing was added or removed.

The partition table is like this:

```
1gb - boot partition
8gb - SWAP
980 - / root partition
```

I've been at this for the last 5 hours and can't figure out why it's not working. Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using ISO image mode? Sometimes dd image mode gives error. Also you can try using a different USB drive and write in **dd** as well as **ISO** image mode.

Comment: What is "ISO image mode"? And how is that different from using `dd`?

Comment: If the ISO file is **hybrid** it supports writing to usb in two modes : ISO and dd. In **dd** mode exact copy of ISO file is made; **byte by byte**. The **drawback** is if you wanted to add firmware files you cannot. In **ISO** mode whole capacity of usb is utilised and the usb is formatted such that windows can access it enabling you to add firmware files. The drawback is that bootloading and later process of the media has to be able to handle Windows file system like FAT32/NTFS/exFAT.

Comment: I tried both and still the same thing, also different usb sticks

Comment: @StanleyLEsniak at which step does it fail and are you connected to internet?

Comment: Yes connected to internet and enough hard drive space

Comment: Hmm. Strange. It usually worked for me when I switch the modes.